# sizeof an array of multiple objects always returns 1

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print the length of an array of objects to a page, so I'm using `sizeof($files)` in a loop. However it always returns `1`.

```
<i class="fas fa-paperclip containAttachments"> <span><?php echo sizeof($files);?></span></i>
```

To make sure, I printed the array to the console like this:

```
<script>console.log(<?php echo $files?>);</script>
```

and here is a screenshot of the arrays

[image]

Comment: is it json object? It Yes, try, `echo sizeof(json_decode($files,true));`

Comment: @RahulMeshram yeah it is, that worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to have json object you can do something like that,

```
echo sizeof(json_decode($files,true));
```

Should solve your problem.

[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) — Decodes a JSON string